# represent parent and child relation by dot(.) in python

Tags: python, dictionary

**My input is:**

```
a = {
    "name": "a",
    "address": {
        "state": "b",
        "full": {
            "city": "c"
        }
    }
}
```

**my expected output is:**

```
{
    "name": "a",
    "address.state": "b",
    "address.full.city": "c"
}
```

I have try many time but its very difficult.

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Recursion`

```
input_dict = { "name": "a", "address": { "state": "b", "full": { "city": "c" } } }
def format_dict(input_dict, parent=None, res = {}):
    for k, v in input_dict.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            if parent:
                format_dict(v, f"{parent}.{k}", res)
            else:
                format_dict(v, f"{k}", res)
        else:
            if parent:
                res[f"{parent}.{k}"] = v
            else:
                res[k] = v
a = {}
format_dict(input_dict, None, a)
print(a)
# {'name': 'a', 'address.state': 'b', 'address.full.city': 'c'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
list(pd.json_normalize(YourDict).T.to_dict().values())[0]
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'a', 'address.state': 'b', 'address.full.city': 'c'}
```